# Insert data in table after verifying username and password

Tags: mysql, insert, verification

I have a php file which retrieves 4 parameters: username,password,barcode,count.
I want to INSERT the username barcode and count into a table "users_products" after checking if the username and password matches each other (from another table "users")

So the code would be something like:

`IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $username AND password = $password) THEN
INSERT INTO users_products (username, barcode, count) VALUES ('username','barcode','count');`

This code is not working, this isnt even real syntax i guess, but i think everybody understands what i want. Thanks for every help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a 'select' from the 'users' table to populate `users_products` to force the user to exist for the query to return results.  This is called ["insert...select" syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) and I think is part of  sql standard as well as being supported in mysql.

```
INSERT INTO users_products (username, barcode, count) 
SELECT username, 'barcode', 'count' 
FROM users 
WHERE username = 'username' AND password = 'password';
```

This selects `username` column and some statically defined fields from `users` and then inserts the data, including static values, into `users_products`.  Number of rows inserted will tell you whether the username and password matched.

`'username'`, `'password'`, `'barcode'`, and `'count'` are assumedly user provided and should be interpolated into a prepared statement to avoid SQL Injection vulnerability.

In the real world, it's uncommon to have username and password be the primary identifier of a user's session.  Usually username and password or other credentials are provided at login, a user session is created, a session cookie is returned to the user, and that cookie is used to refer to session data on the server side.  It's more efficient to write this kind of data with a numeric ID column than a string, and will minimize the password being sent across the wire.  Of course, I say this in ignorance of what you're actually doing.

Another thing: don't store passwords in plain text.  Instead store a crypted version of the password and apply the same crypt to any user supplied password to verify it.  SQL vulnerabilities in databases storing plaintext passwords is a significant part of the security problem online today.

Comment: Its working perfectly fine for now, thank you for the code and also thank you for the hint how to do it properly, i didnt know that there is a better way to do it, i will look into it